# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request' - googletrans

Tags: python, google-translate, googletrans

I am trying to use this google translate python library `googletrans 3.0.0`, which I installed from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/).

I used this code to start with:

```
from googletrans import Translator

proxies = {'http': 'http://myproxy.com:8080', 'https': 'http://myproxy.com:8080'}
translator = Translator(proxies=proxies)
translator.translate("colour")
```

When I call the translator in the last line above, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/alpha/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
  File "/home/alpha/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googletrans/client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
  File "/home/alpha/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googletrans/gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "/home/alpha/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googletrans/gtoken.py", line 54, in _update
    r = self.client.get(self.host)
  File "/home/alpha/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 755, in get
    return self.request(
  File "/home/alpha/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 600, in request
    return self.send(
  File "/home/alpha/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 620, in send
    response = self.send_handling_redirects(
  File "/home/alpha/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 647, in send_handling_redirects
    response = self.send_handling_auth(
  File "/home/alpha/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 684, in send_handling_auth
    response = self.send_single_request(request, timeout)
  File "/home/alpha/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 714, in send_single_request
    ) = transport.request(
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request'
```

Is it the way I am inputting the proxies information to the `Translator` that makes it unhappy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be very confusing according to the official docs, but [this github issue has a solution](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/182#issuecomment-676140624).

For some reason the docs specify both strings and HTTPTransports but this has been clarified in the issue above.

Basically:

```py
from httpcore import SyncHTTPProxy
from googletrans import Translator

http_proxy = SyncHTTPProxy((b'http', b'myproxy.com', 8080, b''))
proxies = {'http': http_proxy, 'https': http_proxy }

translator = Translator(proxies=proxies)
translator.translate("colour")
```

Comment: I replaced 'myproxy.com' with my proxy IP address, like '123.456.789.101', and the 8080 with my proxy port number, but I got now `File "/home/alpha/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googletrans/gtoken.py", line 62, in _update  code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`; which I think is a different problem now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've encountered that too, try `pip install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1`

Comment: I have tried to install this version and it worked, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can also set some environment variables.
For Windows:
cmd:

```
    set http_proxy=...
    set https_proxy=...
```

powershell:

```
    $env:http_proxy = ...; $env:https_proxy = ...
```

For Linux:

```
    export http_proxy=... https_proxy=...
```